# Based on internet connection change color of button to green or grey

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the button itself to change its color when online(based on internet connection) to green otherwise gray.

I have a JS fiddle which gives a solution to click the button and we can see if we are online/offline by an alert.

Can someone please help

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
  <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
    <h3>First Page</h3> <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a> </div>
  <div data-role="content"> <a data-role="button" id="check-connection">Check internet connection</a> </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#check-connection', function() {
    var status = navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline';
    (alert(status));
  });
});
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/VXWGG/1/).

Comment: Just move the code from the click handler to where it's executed right away: http://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/VXWGG/278/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dn7zjm41/

I just added an `if` statement:

```
if(status==="online") {
  $("#check-connection > span").css("background-color", "green");
} else if(status==="offline") {
  $("#check-connection > span").css("background-color", "gray");
} else {
  // the code for another scenario
}
```

And if you want an automatic run without click event - here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/f6paa9xy/

In this case your Javascript should look like this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function() {             
  var status = navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline';
  alert(status);
  if(status==="online") {
    $("#check-connection > span").css("background-color", "green");
  } else if(status==="offline") {
    $("#check-connection > span").css("background-color", "red");
  }
});
```

**Hope it helps**

Comment: Thank you so much @Commercial , similarly is there a way to make this happen without a click and automatically the button goes green or gray based on internet connection.

Comment: @Bob, i have updated the answer, check the last fiddle)

Comment: Yes this is perfect when internet is there its showing green, but when I try turning off the internet it won't go gray. But thank you so much

Comment: Only when I turn off the internet we need to refresh the page in which case the whole page would say lost internet. But we just want the button to change its color to gray when the internet connection is lost. Hope you might have a trick to do that :)

Comment: @Bob, when the connection is OK, it returns "online". So for another scenario I have added "offline", but if it returns another string (not "offline"), just replace it and everything will be OK

Comment: @Bob i can't do it on the fly, it's more complex) but i can try to do it next evening, if you will not solve this problem until that time, My time is 3.53 am now)

Comment: Sure @Commercial Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a simple css class to do this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#check-connection', function(){
    var status = navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline';
    this.className = 'status-'+status;
});
```

```css
.status-online{ background-color: green; }
.status-offline{ background-color: grey; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="content">
    <a data-role="button" id="check-connection">
      Check internet connection
  </a>
</div>
```

However, if you want a live determination, you can use an event listener provided by the browser, most support this (ie8+ for example):

```
window.addEventListener("offline", function() { 
    $("#check-connection")[0].className = "status-offline"; 
});
window.addEventListener("online", function() { 
    $("#check-connection")[0].className = "status-online"; 
});
```

More on this at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine

Comment: Thank you @Travis this is very close, but is there a way it automatically goes green and gray without any click function.

Comment: @Bob - If that was the case, then you would not use the navigator. See my edit

Comment: Thanks @Travis I will look into it, hopefully I have enough insight to have an answer now.

Comment: Hey @Travis used your idea and it worked like a charm :)